# Nested for loop in R for going through each row of each column of a data frame

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, nested-loops

I am trying this nested R loop but the current script writes always `no`. Basically I want it to go over each row of the first column in "dta", check if that string is present in the rows of "samples" and write yes or no. The issue is that I do not know how to code it to go over each row of each column of "samples".

```
dta<-data.frame(Symbol=c("BRAF", "TP53" , "RAS"), Samp1 = c("NA","NA","NA"), Samp2 =c("NA","NA","NA"), Samp3 = c("NA","NA","NA"))


samples<-data.frame(Samp1=c("RAS", "NA"), Samp2=c("RAS", "TP53"), Samp3=c("BRAF", "NA"))
```

The output I expect would be like:

```
Symbol  Samp1   Samp2   Samp3
BRAF    no  no  yes
TP53    no  yes no
RAS yes yes no
```

How can I specify to loop over each column j in "samples"?
I know I am missing something in `dta[i,]<-'Yes'` and `dta[i,]<-'No'`

```
for (j in colnames(samples)){
  for (i in 1:nrow(dta)){
    if(dta[i,1]%in%samples[j]){
      dta[i,]<-'Yes'
    }else(
      dta[i,]<-'No'
    )
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: There is `mtabulate` from the [`qdapTools`](http://trinker.github.io/qdapTools/) package: `library(qdapTools); t(mtabulate(samples))`